# Issue with java.security.InvalidKeyException: Supplied key (sun.security.mscapi.RSAPrivateKey) is not a RSAPrivateKey instance

Tags: java, bouncycastle

Facing issue when getting certificate from windows Keystore. I think system generated certificate/private key is of type sun.security.mscapi.RSAPrivateKey, I need to convert or access it in java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey type.

I have seen several posts over the internet with users facing the same problem but not found single clear post contains the exact solution to the problem.

Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Supplied key (sun.security.mscapi.RSAPrivateKey) is not a RSAPrivateKey instance